# Scheme: How to expand a pattern with multiple variables in syntax-rules without parens

Tags: macros, scheme, syntax-rules

I'm trying to write a macro in Scheme for Picolisp style `let` expressions, let's call this macro `let-slim`. In order to be more terse (like Picolisp) I want their usage to look something like this when declaring only one variable

```
(let-slim var-name initial-value
  (display var-name))
```

Or something like this to declare any number of variables (note that this is pseudocode, I wouldn't actually include the elipses)

```
(let-slim (var-name-1 initital-value-1
           var-name-2 initital-value-2
           ...
           var-name-n initital-value-n)
  (+ var-name-1 var-name-2 ... var-name-n))
```

The first usecase is fairly trivial to write a `syntax-rules` matching pattern for, but the latter I am struggling with.

This doesn't work because only `init` gets repeated

```
(define-syntax let-slim
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(_ (var init ...) body ...)
     (let ((var init) ...)
       body ... )]))
```

This doesn't work because it's considered a misplaced elipsis

```
(define-syntax let-slim
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(_ (var ... init ...) body ...)
     (let ((var init) ...)
       body ... )]))
```

And this doesn't work because I need to use parens at the reference point (which means it changes absolutely nothing as compared to the built-in `let`)

```
(define-syntax let-slim
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(_ (var init) ...) body ...)
     (let ((var init) ...)
       body ... )]))
```

So, is there a way to repeat 2 variables in `syntax-rules` without needing to wrap them in parens, or do I need to use a different macro system (ie `syntax-case` or `defmacro`)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not optimal doing this with `syntax-rules`, but since it is turing complete it can be done:

```
(define-syntax let-slim
  (syntax-rules (pair)
    ((_ pair bindings () body)
     (let bindings . body))
    ((_ pair (acc ...) (k v . rest) body)
     (let-slim pair (acc ... (k v)) rest body))
    ((_ (elements ...) . body)
     (let-slim pair () (elements ...) body))))
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to do this in one go with syntax-rules `...` feature, but you may be able to do it with syntax-rules using recursion:

```
(define-syntax let-slim
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((let-slim (var-1 val-1 . rest) . body)
     (let-slim var-1 val-1 (let-slim rest . body)))
    ((let-slim var val . body) 
     ;; single binding case you already implemented
     ))
```

The only problem is that syntax-rules can't tell that 'var' is supposed to be a symbol. You wont get good error messages from a macro like this (for example if it's used with an odd number of var/val bindings). It may be better to implement this macro with syntax-case. The reason it's difficult to implement is because it's kind of violating the idea of using a pair of brackets for each AST node.

Comment: I do not believe your example code works as-is. In the first case, the body should be inside of the recursive call to let-slim, and written in that manner it seems to eventually expand to a reference to (let-slim () . body), which has no appropriate matching case.  I got it to work by adding such a case, but that would allow the end-user to use (let-slim () . body) at any point, which might be a little silly. I think I'll look into using syntax-case, but if you know of a solution to that last issue let me know.